# Eslint throws is assigned a value but never used , webpack module

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

I am importing a script in webpack, it all works but eslint is throwing the error `'modal is assigned a value but never used'`. Do have to declare the const as a global or export the module to fix the error ?

modules.vanillaModal.js :

```
import VanillaModal from 'vanilla-modal';

// Create instance
const modal = new VanillaModal({
  modal: '.c-modal',
  modalInner: '.js-modal__inner',
  modalContent: '.js-modal__content',
  open: '[rel="js-modal:open"]',
  close: '[rel="js-modal:close"]',
  class: 'js-modal--visible',
  loadClass: 'js-modal--loaded',
});
```

and my webpack entry 
index.js:

```
require('./modules.vanillaModal.js');
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is an eslint rule http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars. It prevents you from creating variables that you never use, which causes code clutter or could mean you're using variables that aren't what you think they are.

If you're using a poorly designed library where the class constructor has side effects (which it isn't supposed to), and you don't need to do anything with the returned value from the class, I would disable that specific eslint rule for the create line with [eslint disable comments](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments-1):

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const modal = new VanillaModal({
  modal: '.c-modal',
  modalInner: '.js-modal__inner',
  modalContent: '.js-modal__content',
  open: '[rel="js-modal:open"]',
  close: '[rel="js-modal:close"]',
  class: 'js-modal--visible',
  loadClass: 'js-modal--loaded',
});
```

You can also wrap any block of code with eslint specific comments to disable a rule for that block:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
const modal = new VanillaModal({
    ...
});
/* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
```

Comment: Or, more specifically, just that rule: `/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/`

Comment: good call @cartant I didn't know you could do specific rules. editing

Comment: The [re-enabling is specific](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments), too: /*eslint-enable no-unused-vars*/

Comment: what a world we live in

Comment: While this works, I discovered that it also prevents other Lint errors from showing, which is bad.

Comment: @AndroidDev see the last comment in the code block. It reenables the rule

Comment: In case of TypeScript use `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` instead of `no-unused-vars`

Answer (score 4):

Add `"varsIgnorePattern:"` to `.eslintrc` file

`"no-unused-vars": ["warn", { "varsIgnorePattern": "VARIABLE_NAME"}]`

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of the `no-unused-vars` rule, you should be able to just add an EsLint configuration comment to declare the variable as **exported** to be used elsewhere.

```
/*exported modal*/
const modal = new VanillaModal({
  modal: '.c-modal',
  modalInner: '.js-modal__inner',
  modalContent: '.js-modal__content',
  open: '[rel="js-modal:open"]',
  close: '[rel="js-modal:close"]',
  class: 'js-modal--visible',
  loadClass: 'js-modal--loaded',
});
```

It will work with constants too.

I find this better than disabling and re-enabling the rule again because I just need one comment instead of two.

Comment: This didn't work for me and the `no-unused-vars` rule is pretty obvious for the next developer so I think it's a better approach.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have `.eslintrc.js` file ?

simply add :

```
"rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": 0
}
```