# Why does the Google Maps Map() constructor have side effects?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, eslint

I've been working a personal Vue project that includes a simple Google map.

While implementing the [Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map), I annoyingly kept encountering the ESLint error `'map' is assigned a value but never used`. I understand why I'm getting this error—The Map() constructor returns a value that I don't need to do anything with:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(el, options)
```

So I eventually just implemented the solution described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41604210/8245557) to bypass the lint rule.

> If you're using a poorly designed library where the class constructor has side effects (which it isn't supposed to), and you don't need to do anything with the returned value from the class, I would disable that specific eslint rule for those lines.

However, my question is, why is Google's Map() constructor designed in this way? I have a hard time believing this library would be "poorly designed" but can't see a reason for this implementation.

Comment: a) old age and backwards-compatibility b) ease of use

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic - we can only guess about the reasons

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry, I should clarify why I'm asking: When I get a lint error that requires suppressing a rule, especially when working with a widely implemented library like G Maps, I usually assume I'm doing something that is bad form. So I wanted to get insights to validate my solution. I don't think you have to have built the API to be able to provide answers as to why it is designed a certain way.

Comment: Well, either you are doing something wrong (here: by writing code that does nothing, and could just be removed), or if the code does something useful, then yes the designers of the library have chosen a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not side effect. It's returning instance of it. So you can call further [methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map) on it

Comment: But OP doesn't call any methods on it. If the constructed wouldn't have any side effects, the code could be removed entirely.